# Cannot Catch Body From Request

Tags: kotlin, jackson, ktor

I have an issue with catching data from request body. I know this might be very easy question but I have looking for that in google and ktor docs and havent find solution.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, module = Application::mainModule)
    server.start()
}
fun Application.mainModule() {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        jackson {
            enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
        }
    }
    routing {
        post("/") {
            val parameters = call.receiveParameters()
            println(parameters)
        }
    }
}
```

Sending body in request:

```
{
    "nick": "xxx"
}
```

Errors:

```
ERROR ktor.application - Unhandled: POST - /
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `io.ktor.http.Parameters` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (InputStreamReader); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1589)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1055)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:265)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3218)
    at io.ktor.jackson.JacksonConverter.convertForReceive(JacksonConverter.kt:44)
    at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$3.invokeSuspend(ContentNegotiation.kt:169)
    at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$3.invoke(ContentNegotiation.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:318)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:163)
```

Comment: A [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-678) already exists for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
routing {
        post("/") {
            val parameters = call.receive<String>()
            println(parameters)
        }
    }
```

You are using call.receiveParameters, but are passing a json body. =p